# Someone damages tefillin that he borrowed from someone else. Is he liable?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, borrowing

From Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 10:22:

מֻתָּר לִקַּח תְּפִלִּין שֶׁל חֲבֵרוֹ גַּם שֶׁלֹּא בִידִיעָתוֹ לְהָנִיחָן וּלְבָרֵךְ עֲלֵיהֶן, כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתַבְתִּי בְּסִימָן שֶׁלִּפְנֵי זֶה סָעִיף י"א לְעִנְיַן טַלִּית (י"ד ל' ס"ו).

One is allowed to take someone else's Tefillin even without the owner's knowledge and say a blessing on them, as explained in ch. 11.

There, in discussing that one can take someone else's Tallit, based on a principle that one is happy when someone borrows something for the purpose of a mitzvah (if I understand the underlying principle of what he says. I'm not doing a literal translation.)

Let's say while borrowing the tefillin, the strap tears accidentally. Is the person liable to pay for or replace the strap?

The person is considered a "sho'el" - borrower. Under the normal principles of borrowing, he is liable for all damages. However, in this case, perhaps, the strap was so weak already that it may have torn anyway the next time the owner would have put it on. (I.e. - at the time the borrower took the tefillin, there were no noticeable signs of a weak strap or any other noticeable damage, but something accidental occurred. Chances are, if there was some noticeable weak strap, the person might not have borowed the strap to start, as a torn strap would make the tefillin *pasul*, and the borrower wouldn't care to take the risk, and would rather have borrowed a sturdier pair.)

Also, if it is assumed that the owner allows anyone to use his tefillin automatically, does the owner in a sense relinquish unknown borrowers from accidental damage as well?

Comment: If there was due cause to be concerned that it would break during use, the original owner probably would never have allowed it to be borrowed, in which case the whole *heter* of the KS"A would fall apart and the "borrower" would be liable as a thief. If it was an unexpectable *oness*, however, he would at best still be liable as a borrower.

Comment: @Loewian But if a person _wants_ a Mitzva to be done, then maybe he is a Socher. (Truth is, it's hard to believe, but I'm asking in the spirit of DoubleAA.) But that's an interesting Svara. You are basically saying that מתה מחמת מלאכה won't apply for borrowing without his knowledge.

Comment: @HaLeiVi I thought of that also ala a shomer aveida being considered a shomer sachar. But as you say, I doubt the KSA goes to that extent though who knows. I think possibly the Mishna Berura(?) says the kula doesnt apply by seforim becasue they're likely to tear, though more recent poskim (Rav Yaakov Kamenetsky?) say that nowadays since seforim are cheap, the kula is applicable.

Comment: "However, in this case, perhaps, the strap was so weak already that it may have torn anyway the next time the owner would have put it on." I assume you're asking [not about a case in which the strap was weak](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) but, rather, assuming that "maybe it was weak" is an argument one can make in *any* case, i.e. even without knowing it was weak. Right?

Comment: Isn't this just Metah Machmat Melacha? @Loewian , HaLeiVi

Comment: More interesting question would be if I "gave" someone my arba minim to perform the mitzvah and they dropped the esrog and broke its pitum...

Comment: @msh210 Correct, and I shall edit. I guess that if the borrower saw that the strap was weak, perhaps, he would not have borrowed it in the first place. The torn strap would make the tefillin *passul*, and a borrower who would see a strap about to tear would most likely not borrow the tefillin.

Comment: @CashCow Regarding Arba Minim, as I understand it, you give it as a gift. That means that the other person now owns it. Granted, the protocol is that the other person gives it back to you as a present. But, it seems that while the other person has full ownership, it is his! Interesting question which you may want to put as a full M.Y. question.

Comment: @Loewian If I remember the footnote from Daily Halachah Discussion by Rabbi Neustadt correctly, he quotes Rav Elyashiv as being of the opinion that Sefarim are included in the 'implied permissions' category (not to say that Rav Yaakov wasn't of that opinion too).

Comment: Like what @DoubleAA was referring to, why would this be different than any other standard case of Shomer? This person with implied permission becomes one of the categories of Shomrim (you suggested Sho'el, which sounds right to me), and has all the same rules as any other Sho'el. If it was an Oness/Geneivah/P'shiyah he's obligated. If it's Metah Machmat Melacha, he's exempt. Why would the owner be assumed to give special dispensations?

Comment: "However, in this case, perhaps, the strap was so weak already that it may have torn anyway the next time the owner would have put it on." Why is that any different from the normal shoel situation?

Comment: @Daniel If, in fact, he is considered a "Sho'el" as any other, then there is no difference AFAICT. Is he considered a Sho'el, here?

Comment: I think I'm struggling to understand this part of your question: "The person is considered a "sho'el" - borrower. Under the normal principles of borrowing, he is liable for all damages. However, in this case, perhaps, the strap was so weak already that it may have torn anyway the next time the owner would have put it on." You seem to make a distinction between this case and a normal borrowing case, but I don't understand why your distinction constitutes a distinction.

Comment: For the record: The Aruch Hashulchan says that nowadays people are more sensitive, and you can't take it for granted that he'd want you to bind his hygienic Tefilin on your (potentially) sweaty arm.